# Как обновить компонент JSF на странице из диалогового окна?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Добрый день! После ввода данных в диалоговое окно, стоит задача обновить таблицу treeTable библиотеки Primefaces, расположенную на странице, откуда диалоговое окно было вызвано. 
Вот окно:

```
<h:body>
<div class="add_goods_dialog">
    <h:form>

        <p:panel id="panel" header="Поля, отмеченные *, обязательны для заполнения">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                <h:outputLabel for="name" value="#{msg.name}*" />
                <p:inputText id="name" required="true" value="#{goodsController.name}"/>
                <h:outputLabel for="price" value="#{msg.price}*" />
                <p:inputText id="price" required="false" value="#{goodsController.price}"/>
                <h:outputLabel for="man" value="#{msg.manufacturer}" />
                <p:inputText id="man" required="false" value="#{goodsController.manufacturer}"/>
                <h:outputLabel  for="descr" value="#{msg.description}" />
                <p:inputTextarea style="width: 450px" id="descr" required="false" value="#{goodsController.description}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
        <p:commandButton styleClass="table_button" value="#{msg.save}" update=":admin_table"
                         actionListener="#{goodsController.addGoods}">
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

А вот фрагмент самой страницы:

```
 <h:form>

            <p:treeTable id="admin_table"  value="#{tableController.root}" var="g" selectionMode="single" selection="#{tableController.selectedNode}" style="margin-top:0">
                <p:column headerText="#{msg.name}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{g.name}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:treeTable>

            <p:commandButton styleClass="table_button" value="#{msg.add_goods}"  icon="ui-icon-plus"
                             actionListener="#{tableController.addGoodsDialog}">
</h:form>
```

При открытии окна появляется ошибка:

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.handleRenderException Error Rendering View[/pages/addGoods.xhtml] 
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with expression ":admin_table" referenced from "j_idt8:j_idt14".
at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentInternal(SearchExpressionFacade.java:422)
at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentForClient(SearchExpressionFacade.java:200)
at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentsForClient(SearchExpressionFacade.java:147)
at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.addExpressions(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:92)
at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.update(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:85)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.buildAjaxRequest(CoreRenderer.java:352)
at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.buildRequest(CommandButtonRenderer.java:123)
at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(CommandButtonRenderer.java:65)
at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(CommandButtonRenderer.java:54)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1896)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
введите сюда код
```

У родительских элементов на странице идентификаторов нет, т.е. id="admin_table" никуда не вложен. 
 Собственно, как надо правильно прописать путь для этого компонента? Или в данном случае вообще как-то по другому надо делать? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Используйте update by styleClass, поддерживаемый движков Primefaces.

```
<p:treeTable id="admin_table" styleClass="admin_table" ...>

<p:commandButton update="@(.admin_table)" ...>
```

> У родительских элементов на странице идентификаторов нет, т.е. id="admin_table" никуда не вложен.

Вот это уже заблуждение, элементы jsf вкладываются к контейнеры (form, dialog, composite component) даже если им не присвоен id. Ссылка вида :admin_table в вашем случаи некорректна, поскольку нет компонента в корне страницы с ид admin_table. Абсолютная адресация должна выглядеть так :idForm:idTarget, опять же id формы нужно знать.

Answer (score 0):

Если мне не изменяет память, тот update без указания id формы работает внутри текущей. Для того чтобы заработало в другой форме надо указать формам  id и в аттрибут update записывать ":formId:admin_table" т.е.:

```
<div class="add_goods_dialog">
    <h:form id="popup_form">

        <p:panel id="panel" header="Поля, отмеченные *, обязательны для заполнения">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                <h:outputLabel for="name" value="#{msg.name}*" />
                <p:inputText id="name" required="true" value="#{goodsController.name}"/>
                <h:outputLabel for="price" value="#{msg.price}*" />
                <p:inputText id="price" required="false" value="#{goodsController.price}"/>
                <h:outputLabel for="man" value="#{msg.manufacturer}" />
                <p:inputText id="man" required="false" value="#{goodsController.manufacturer}"/>
                <h:outputLabel  for="descr" value="#{msg.description}" />
                <p:inputTextarea style="width: 450px" id="descr" required="false" value="#{goodsController.description}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
        <p:commandButton styleClass="table_button" value="#{msg.save}" update=":main_form:admin_table"
                         actionListener="#{goodsController.addGoods}">
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</div>


<h:form id="main_form">

        <p:treeTable id="admin_table"  value="#{tableController.root}" var="g" selectionMode="single" selection="#{tableController.selectedNode}" style="margin-top:0">
            <p:column headerText="#{msg.name}">
                <h:outputText value="#{g.name}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:treeTable>

        <p:commandButton styleClass="table_button" value="#{msg.add_goods}"  icon="ui-icon-plus"
                         actionListener="#{tableController.addGoodsDialog}">
</h:form>
```

Comment: Я так уже пробовал, это работает только если обе формы находятся на одной странице.   В итоге получилось, когда добавил для вызывающей диалог кнопки:   `<p:commandButton styleClass="table_button" value="#{msg.add_goods}"  icon="ui-icon-plus"
                                 actionListener="#{tableController.addGoodsDialog}">
                    <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{tableController.init}" update="admin_table messages"/>
                </p:commandButton>`